# How to call another class file in netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I have an interface design in netbeans and another java class file in same pacage. I want to call the class file when the button clicks. How can i do this? Please remember that i am new to java. here is the button action perform field

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}
```

and i want to call the

```
public class comments {
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
```

class file.

Comment: new Comments().main(null)

Comment: but it does not call the comments class insted it creates a new void main. so what can i do? I also appriciate your contribution.

Comment: sorry i can't get you

Comment: it gives me an error Surround Statement with try-catch

Comment: sorr it was my fault. I have fixed it. I really appriciate your contribution. Thank you.